# I am trying to show monthly graduation in the date axe using ggplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to show monthly graduation in the date axe but that's not working:

```
p2 <- ggplot()
p2 <- p2 + geom_line(mapping=aes(x=as.Date(X2), y=X1,color="red"), data=data , size=.1, alpha=1) 
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_date(format = "%Y-%b")
p2

Error in continuous_scale(aesthetics, "date", identity, breaks = breaks,  : 
  unused argument (format = "%Y-%b")
```

someone can help please ?

Comment: The error message tells you that `format` is not a valid argument for `scale_x_date`. Please read the help text http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_date.html, and you will find examples on how to use the arguments `breaks = date_breaks()` and `labels = date_format()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
library(scales)
scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%b"))
```

Comment: > p2 <- ggplot()
> p2 <- p2 + geom_line(mapping=aes(x=as.Date(X2), y=X1,color="red"), data=data , size=.1, alpha=1)
> p2 <- p2+scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%b"))
Error in structure(list(call = match.call(), aesthetics = aesthetics,  : 
  could not find function "date_format"
> p2